# Using reduce and sort together (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, reduce

I have an array of objects (groceryArray) that I would like to organize into an object by the groupId property (object keys) and finally sort these keys by the groupDisplayOrder property. See finalOutput for desired result.

```
const groceryArray = [
    { id: 'apples', groupId: 'produce', groupDisplayOrder: 1 },
    { id: 'chicken', groupId: 'meat', groupDisplayOrder: 3 },
    { id: 'shrimp', groupId: 'seafood', groupDisplayOrder: 4 },
    { id: 'milk', groupId: 'dairy', groupDisplayOrder: 2 },
    { id: 'carrots', groupId: 'produce', groupDisplayOrder: 1 },
    { id: 'salmon', groupId: 'seafood', groupDisplayOrder: 4 }
]
```

**Desired Result**

```
const finalOutput = {
    produce: [{ id: 'apples', groupId: 'produce', groupDisplayOrder: 1 }, { id: 'carrots', groupId: 'produce', groupDisplayOrder: 1 }],
    dairy: [{ id: 'milk', groupId: 'dairy', groupDisplayOrder: 2 }],
    meat: [{ id: 'chicken', groupId: 'meat', groupDisplayOrder: 3 }],
    seafood: [{ id: 'shrimp', groupId: 'seafood', groupDisplayOrder: 4 }, { id: 'salmon', groupId: 'seafood', groupDisplayOrder: 4 }]
}
```

Here's my current code ... I think I may be doing too many steps. I'm wondering if there is a way to reduce and sort at the same time?

```
  const groceriesGroupedById = groceryArray.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    if (cur.groupId) {
      (acc[cur.groupId] || (acc[cur.groupId] = [])).push(cur)
    }
    return acc
  }, {})

  const sortedGroupIds = Object.keys(groceriesGroupedById).sort((a, b) => {
    return groceriesGroupedById[a][0].groupDisplayOrder - groceriesGroupedById[b][0].groupDisplayOrder
  })

  const finalOutput = sortedGroupIds.reduce((acc, key) => ( acc[key] = groceriesGroupedById[key], acc ), {})
```

Comment: Who closed this? Can you please reopen... this is different as I am asking to group and sort...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, sort array using [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const groceryArray = [
    { id: 'apples', groupId: 'produce', groupDisplayOrder: 1 },
    { id: 'chicken', groupId: 'meat', groupDisplayOrder: 3 },
    { id: 'shrimp', groupId: 'seafood', groupDisplayOrder: 4 },
    { id: 'milk', groupId: 'dairy', groupDisplayOrder: 2 },
    { id: 'carrots', groupId: 'produce', groupDisplayOrder: 1 },
    { id: 'salmon', groupId: 'seafood', groupDisplayOrder: 4 }
];

groceryArray.sort((a, b) => a.groupDisplayOrder - b.groupDisplayOrder);

const finalOutput = groceryArray.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (!acc[cur.groupId]) acc[cur.groupId] = [];
  acc[cur.groupId].push(cur);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(finalOutput);
```

Comment: Thanks! The goal is to also sort the new object keys by groupDisplayOrder ... e.g dairy should be second key.

Comment: Thank you! Much simpler than what I had :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `Map` and `Array#reduce` you can group the data and then loop over all the values and sort them.

```js
const 
  groceryArray=[{id:"apples",groupId:"produce",groupDisplayOrder:1},{id:"chicken",groupId:"meat",groupDisplayOrder:3},{id:"shrimp",groupId:"seafood",groupDisplayOrder:4},{id:"milk",groupId:"dairy",groupDisplayOrder:2},{id:"carrots",groupId:"produce",groupDisplayOrder:1},{id:"salmon",groupId:"seafood",groupDisplayOrder:4}],

  res = groceryArray.reduce((r, o) => ((r[o.groupId] ??= []), r[o.groupId].push(o), r), {});

Object.values(res).forEach((o) => o.sort(({ groupDisplayOrder: a }, { groupDisplayOrder: b }) => a - b));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: @Michael Please check if this solves your problem, do let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a nested approach by using an array and `groupDisplayOrder` with object with `groupId` as key.

At the end combine all objects into a single object.

```js
const
    groceryArray = [{ id: 'apples', groupId: 'produce', groupDisplayOrder: 1 }, { id: 'chicken', groupId: 'meat', groupDisplayOrder: 3 }, { id: 'shrimp', groupId: 'seafood', groupDisplayOrder: 4 }, { id: 'milk', groupId: 'dairy', groupDisplayOrder: 2 }, { id: 'carrots', groupId: 'produce', groupDisplayOrder: 1 }, { id: 'salmon', groupId: 'seafood', groupDisplayOrder: 4 }],
    result = Object.assign({}, ...groceryArray.reduce((r, o) => {
        ((r[o.groupDisplayOrder] ??= {})[o.groupId] ??= []).push(o);
        return r;
    }, []));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```